# Select the value in the matrix/ array/ list

Tags: python-2.7

I was a beginner in python programming. What is the difference:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

with

```
a = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

I have

```
a = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

I want to form a matrix / array / list with values <= 6, in order to obtain:

```
a1 = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

How do I get the a1?

Sorry if my question has been asked before.

Comment: what should be input and what should be output?

Comment: The first one is a list with 10 elements. The second is not a valid list. If you try to create that list you would get a syntax error. If you want a list with 1 element, you should use `a = ["0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

is a valid list,

```
a = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

is not a valid list

Assuming you want to turn:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

into

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

you could use list comprehension:

```
a1 = [x for x in a if x <= 6]
```

or a for loop:

```
a1 = []
for x in a:
    if x <= 6:
        a1.append(x)
```

The list comprehension solution is more pythonic though.